# Declarative interpretation of a Prolog program that says if a list S is a sublist of another list L

Tags: prolog, declarative

I am new in Prolog and I am studying it for an universitary exam, we use SWI Prolog

I have some problem to understand how work this simple program that say TRUE if a list S is a **sublist** of a list L, otherwise say that the predicate is FALSE.

I have the following solution but I have some problem to understand it's declarative meaning

Reading the book I think that I had have some idea but I am not sure about it...

This is the solution that use concatenation:

```
sublist(S,L) :- conc(L1, L2, L),
            conc(S, L3, L2).

conc([],L,L).

conc([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]) :- conc(L1,L2,L3).
```

This solution use an other litle program that respond TRUE if the third list is the concatenation of the first and the second list.

To say if S i sublist of L have to be TRUE the following two conditions:

1. L have to be a list that is the concatenation of L1 and L2
2. L2 have to be a list that is the concatenation of **S** (my sublist if exist into L list) and another list L3

This is the book explaination but it is just a litle obsucre for me...

I have try to reasoning about it and try to understand what really deeply mean...

So I think that, in some way, it is like to search if an element is member of a list using this other program:

```
member2(X, [X|_]).

member2(X,[_|T]):- member2(X,T).
```

In this program I simply say that if X is the element in the top of the list (its head) then X is in the list and the program respond true. Otherwise, if X element is not in the top of the list (or it is not my solution) I try to search it it the TAIL T of this list.

Back to the sublist program I think that the reasoning is similar

**First I decompose L list in two list L1 and L2** (using conc program)**

**Then I check if it is true that the concatenation of S and L3 is the L2 list.**

If booth these condition it is true then S is sublist of L

I think that the L1 list have a similar role of the X element that I extract from the list in the member program.

Since the sublist S can start at the beginning of the list L, L1 can be [] and I have that I can decompose L in the concatenation of L1=[] and L2 and the I can try to decompose L2 in S and L3.

If I can do this last decomposition then the program end and I can say that it is true that S is a sublist of the original list L

If it is not true that **conc(S, L3, L2)** then ddo backtrack and take an other branch of computation

Is it right my declarative interpretation?

I am finding great difficulties with this example, I have also try to find a procedural explaination (using the operation trace in the Prolog shell) but I have big problem because the computation it is so big also for a short list...

Comment: Would you mind using a spell checker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book explanation is more declarative, because it doesn't invoke Prolog's search mechanism. I would probably write this with more underscores:

```
sublist(S, L) :- append(_, Suffix, L), append(S, _, Suffix).
```

This at least makes the relationship between S and L2 (renamed Suffix) a little more clear. What we're trying to say, and this is hard to express clearly in declarative English, is that **S is a sublist of L if there is a suffix of L called Suffix and S is a prefix of Suffix**. Naming the other constituents only adds confusion. Prolog will internally name these variables and unify something with them as it attempts to unify everything else, but it won't share that information with the caller. Though these variables need to exist in some sense, they aren't germane to your formula or they would not be singletons. Whenever you get a singleton variable warning, replace the variable with the underscore. It will add clarity.

It happens that since the prefixes and suffixes involved can be empty lists, S can be a proper prefix of L or a proper suffix of L and everything will work out.

The declarative reading of `member/2`, for reference, is **X is a member of a list if X is the head of the list or if X is a member of the tail of the list**. Note carefully what is absent: mention of checking, success or failure, or, really, any order of operations. It is equally declarative to say **X is a member of a list if it is a member of the tail or if it is the head.** It is just an unavoidable fact of life that to make a computer perform a calculation it must be done in a certain order, so you have to tell Prolog things in the right order or it will enter infinite loops, but this is not an aspect of logic, just Prolog.

As we've gone over several other times, when you invoke the machinery of Prolog, you are no longer in a declarative reading. So when you say, for instance "First I decompose..." you've already left the declarative world and entered the procedural world. The declarative world doesn't have steps, even though Prolog must do things in a certain order to perform a computation on a real-life computer. Likewise, in a declarative reading you do not *check* things, they simply are or are not. The word *backtrack* also cannot appear as part of a declarative reading. The only "verb" you should be using in a declarative reading is the verb of being, "is."

That said, your Prolog/procedural readings are perfectly correct.

Comment: I accept your response based on trust, now I read it well and try to fully understand what you're explaining :-) Do you think it is normal that at the time, as I can understand a solution like this (studying long and having many doubts) but I would not be able to find it on your own? (without reading the book I mean)

Comment: Well, I am not the only person on S.O. with something to say; CapelliC and false both have decades of experience over me and are likely to correct me, and there are plenty of others too. I would have waited a little longer to accept, but I appreciate that you trust me. :) Yes, I do think it is normal, especially if you have experience programming in other languages. Prolog is *very* different and takes a long time to start making sense. But I think you're ahead of the curve and practice will get you even further. Keep doing what you're doing! :)

Comment: I accept your answer because I had quickly read it and I found that it is good, now I am studyin it :-)

Comment: My email address is in my profile. If you shoot me an email we can do this back-and-forth a little more interactively, and maybe get you prepped for your test a little faster.